# Return multiple values and access them?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How would I structure this to return multiple values (message and name), and be able to access them in the `js.html` file?

--**code.gs**

```
function createArtistTable(name)
{
    var message = "test";

    //return message and name
}
```

--**js.html**

```
function openArtistTable(name)
{
    google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(openSuccess)
        .withFailureHandler(openFailure)
        .createArtistTable(name)
}

function openSuccess(//have 2 values here -- var1, var2)
{
    console.log(var1);
    console.log(var2);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've fixed the problem. Thank you all for the help and information. This is what I changed: http://pastebin.com/Ci1e8ZWx

Comment: Either you can return it as an array or as an object.

Comment: return an object like `{message: message, name: name}`

Comment: @CoderGLM How would I access it in the openSuccess function?

Comment: call `createArtistTable ` in `openSuccess `

Comment: @CoderGLM Something like var x = createArtistTable().message ?

Comment: yes, or you can do like `var obj = createArtistTable(your parameter); `, then you can access **message** by `obj.message`

Answer (score 4):

A function can only return one value.

So the way to do this is to wrap them together inside an array or object.

```
function return2Vals()
{
    var var1;
    var var2;
    //Code that does stuff with var1 and var2
    ///
    ///
    //Create an array with the values and return it.
    var results = [var1, var2];
    return results;
}
```

Using the result:

```
var vals = return2Vals();
console.log("One of the return values is:", vals[0]);
console.log("The other return value is:", vals[1]);
```

Alternatively you could use an object and basically do whatever you want
by using an object:

```
function returnSomeValsAsObj()
{
    var var1;
    var var2;
    //Code that does stuff with var1 and var2
    ///
    ///
    //Create an object with the values and return it.
    var results = {primary_result: var1, secondary_result: var2, accompanying_message: "some message"};
    return results;
}
```

Using:

```
var results = returnSomeValsAsObj();
console.log(results.primary_result);
console.log(results.secondary_result);
console.log(results.accompanying_message);
```

Comment: I tried the second way with the object, but I'm getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: createArtistTable is not defined'. 

http://pastebin.com/cLbD5bWS

Comment: It sounds like it can't find the function. Were you able to call the function before you tried using it to return stuff?

Comment: It's in a separate file. I called it with the openArtistTable function and then it should return what I return from createArtistTable to openSuccess

Comment: The error  'Uncaught ReferenceError: createArtistTable is not defined' means that it doesn't know about a function by that name, so it's not in the same scope. I'm sure how google-apps-script works exactly but it seems like it must be treating those files as different scopes, which you could think of as separate functions that can't really touch each others' code.

What happens if you declare variables of the same name in both files? If it lets you do that, they are different scopes and you'll have to find some way to pass data between those scopes.

Comment: Yes, I can declare two of the same variables. But, If I could pass one variable, why can't I pass two or more?

Comment: Sorry, what I was asking you to test is whether you can make two variables of the same name in both of those files, in order to test if those files share a scope or not. A variable name can only be used once per scope. Same with function names. If they do not share a scope, they can't see each others variables or functions and you will not be able to call a function from the other file.

Comment: As for passing variables to functions, you can pass as many as you want as long as they match the number of parameters in the function definition. The limitation is how many a function can return when it finishes. It can return one thing so that's why you need to put multiple values into one object or array in order to return multiple values.

Comment: It seems from your edit that you managed to gain access to your function across the files. Glad it worked out for you.